# How to clear selections in uitableview and show it dynamically?

Tags: swift, uitableview, dynamic, deselect

I have selected some `tableView` cells and stored it in `UserDefaults`, also showed what i have selected. Now after adding a clear button and made deselect all selected row & emptied the selected row `array` followed by `table reloadAll()`. It is not displaying dynamically? How to clear selections from a button action and show `tableView` without selections immediately?

```
  @IBAction func clearSelection(_ sender: Any) {

//        self.sellerTableView.reloadInputViews()
//
//        self.sellerTableView.deselectRow(at: , animated: true)
```

This one is not working!

```
        if let aRow = self.sellerTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            self.sellerTableView.deselectRow(at: aRow, animated: true)
        }
//        self.userSelectedSellers.removeAll()

        self.sellerTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Add some code to get proper help or suggestion. what have you tried ?

Comment: Is the code enough? @Amit

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way to deselect all cells from a tableView :

```
for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
    cell.setSelected(false, animated: true)
}

tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Its not working. I have put your code in in button(which is outside tableview) action. Also added table reload.

Comment: Yes, simply put this code anywhere (in your IBAction for example)

Answer (score 0):

> As you described above that you have a tableview with multiple
>   selection, you should first create a `array` which adds your selected
>   indexPaths and then you write -

```
if indexArray.contains(indexPath.row) {
*// then set the table cell as selected*
}
else {
*// remove the table view selection*
}
```

You can do the table cell select and deselect as your requirement. like changing the color or place a tick mark .... any think ..

then you do something like this in the didSelect Delegate -

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
if indexArray.contains(indexPath.row) {
        if let indexForRemove = indexArray.index(of: indexPath.row) {
            indexArray.remove(at: iindexForRemove)
        }
    }
    else {
        indexArray.append(indexPath.row)
    }
```

> // Now reload your table view--- Done